# Decode frames from mp4 file while new ones are encoded into it

Tags: video-streaming, decode, mp4, video-capture

I write a video player that shows a live video stream (from camera) and also encodes it into mp4 file at the same time. 
 I want to also be able to playback (seek backward or forward) the video from that mp4 file while the stream continue being encoded to that mp4 file.

Since "moov atom" is only added to the final mp4 file, how can I read from it while the stream is still being encoded to the mp4 file?

What is the best approach?

**UPDATE**

@VC.ONE suggested using a fragmented mp4. But, how to I read those chunks from that fMp4 file? Is there any (C++/C#) library that can find those fragments in the fMp4 file?

Comment: _"...And also encodes it into mp4 file"_ that should be "Also converts it into a fragmented MP4 (or ISOBMFF) format"... This way, the frames or time-range segments are written as chunks that each have their own chunk specific MOOV header, now called a MOOF header for that Fragment. These chunks are playable on their own. They can be saved as either separate chunk files or just stitched together as one file. As long as you can get the bytes, do whichever suits you

Comment: @VC.One, so basically I can save the rtsp stream as fragmeneted mp4? The container is still mp4 but inside it the stream is saved as bunch of "moof-mdat" chunks? How to go through the segments? I cannot find what framework can get those segments from the mp4 file programmatically (C++ or C#)? Does the fMp4 comes with some metadata file so I won't have to iterate through the "moof-mdat" chunks inside the original Mp4 in order to find the correct segment?

Comment: _"I wrote a video player that shows a live video stream (from camera) and also encodes it into mp4 file at the same time."_ Where is the file being saved? Use a **Hex editor** (download one for your O.S) to preview the file bytes, then write code to find the same required data. Make a test video file of 10 seconds and let me know where you're stuck with it (share video link for faster advice).

Comment: @VC.One, my mistake. I meant "I wr-i-te a video player...". I'll update my post. The video streamed via rtsp will be saved to a file. Are you saying there is no library that can find those chunks in the mp4 file, but I have manually deserialize the bytes myself and calculate the mdat inside the chunk?

Comment: @VC.One, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You didn't give info on how you are playing the MP4 file? The fragmented format one should be understandable to the same MPEG decoder you are using for the MP4 playback. Now either you are saving one long f-MP4 file so make sure can do multiple "read" on those bytes (some systems lock the file from external reads while writing is in progress)... or else you are saving chunks as separate files (usually as `.m4s` for MP4 segment).... Now if chunks you can just load each file into your player (via file paths) or if one long file (then you read new sections and give to decoder)